# Simple form submission angular & Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im having trouble submit a form to firebase. Ive tried playing around with differnent event listeners and ways to the call the function but cant get the data to firebase. Here is what I currnetly have

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://site.firebaseio.com/things");
var postRef = firebaseRef.push();

$scope.submitPost = function(){
    firebaseRef.push = ({Title: $scope.title, Description:   $scope.moreinfo, Email: $scope.email, Number: $scope.number, Date: $scope.rtime});
    console.log('dome');
};
```

HTML

```
 //divs all look like this for different inputs

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label> 
    <input id="phone" ng-model="phone" 
    type="text>
</div>
```

Submit

Comment: What you are doing is not Angular. Moreover totally off jQuery design can be a reason why it doesn' work. Try to do it properly using ngModel and ngClick. And remove jQuery if you care about your app.

Comment: Where is the angular code? It is not an angular form.

Comment: @MohaiminMoin,  I updated it, let me know what you think! thanks'

Comment: Change the code to `firebaseRef.push({Title: $scope.title, Description:   $scope.moreinfo, Email: $scope.email, Number: $scope.number, Date: $scope.rtime});` Also see: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push

Answer (score 0):

`push` is a function with signature :

```
push() - push([value], [onComplete])
Generates a new child location using a unique key and returns a Firebase reference to it.
```

see the documentation here.
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html

usage example

```
var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/message_list');
    messageListRef.push({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });
// Same effect as the previous example, but we've combined the push() and the set().
```